# Expression Blend crashes when accessing Asset library

Tags: silverlight, expression-blend-4

i developped a silverlight 3 application in Visual Studio 2008 and Expression Blend 3. Some weeks ago I ported the app to silverlight 4 and upgraded my tools to Expression Blend 4 and Visual Studio 2010.

All works fine in Visual Studio. I can select my custom controls (which are defined in the application, it's not a foreign assembly) from the toolbox and place them in the designer. But if I do this in Expression Blend 4 by using the asset library, Expression Blend crashes without an error message on opening the asset library. The same when I write a "<" in the xaml code (normally Expression Blend should show the Intellisense).

With the help of Process Monitor I discovered that Blend is crashing because it doesn't find the assembly of my silverlight app at C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\Silverlight\v4.0. Why does Blend search there? When I copy the assembly to that location all works fine. But that can't be the solution?!

Thanks for any hints and suggestions!
Levi

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I had a solution for it. It's working fine. But I don't know it is eligible to use.

Delete files inside bin folder. (Debug and Release).

Then Run the project using Expression Blend. Then build the project. This might work.

Thank you.